# Django: Link data to ManyToManyField

Tags: django, python-3.6

For example, in Django, you create models called "Skill" and "Person" and associate them with models.ManyToManyField from Person side. Skill has a score attribute, the higher the score of that skill, the higher the skill.

Then, in the Project attribute on the Person side, items like "Skill A: 87", "Skill B: 45", "Skill C: 62", "Skill D: 100" ,,,, are lined up.

Ideally, you want to enter numerical values for each item side by side like "Skill A", "Skill B", "Skill C", "Skill D" ,,,.

How can I do this? It seems that it is hard to find out how to combine an associative array and models.ManyToManyField.

Comment: Create a project model that links users with skills.

Comment: I would assume that skills have different scores for each person, so you shouldn't have the `score` attribute within the `Skill` model as it will cause every `Person` who have that `Skill` to have the same score. See [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for an alternative implementation idea.